In which episode did Joey teach Ross on how to caress a face?
I recall an episode of Friends with Ross telling Joey about a woman putting her fingers on his face and interpreting that as flirting. Joey, being a master at seduction, showed what actually caressing one's face in flirting is like, and Ross was smitten by that simple demonstration.

I think it's "The one with the Blackout" (season 1 episode 7), the woman that put her fingers on his hair (not his face) is Rachel, and Joey says that Ross is in the friend zone.
How to know you're in the Friendzone

I think's it's actually between Joey and Chandler, and Joey actually caresses his thigh, rather than his face. 
"The One With Ross' Tan " from Season 10:

[Scene: Joey and Rachel's apartment]
Chandler: So, you and Rachel tonight, uh?
Joey: Yeah. It's actually our first official date
Chandler: Wow! So tonight may be the night! You're nervous?
Joey: Naa, no. This is the part I'm actually good at.
Chandler: What must it be like not to be crippled by fear and
  self-loathing.
Joey: (pause) It's OK!
Chandler: How can you be so confident?
Joey: Well, I... I know exactly what I'm gonna do!
Chandler: Really? Like you have a routine?
Joey: No, no no no no. See. Each woman is different.You have to
  appreciate their uniqueness.
Chandler: Really?
Joey: No, I do six things! First, I look deep in her eyes. Then, I
  kiss her. Next I take my hand and I softly graze her thigh.
Chandler: You mean like this? (he starts touching his thigh in a funny
  and awkward way)
Joey: NO! Not like that, no no. No, like this. (He starts lightly
  grazing Chandler's thigh)
Chandler: Oh, I see what you mean, that's quite nice. (They look at
  each other, both embarassed)
Joey: More foosball?
Chandler: ...and beer!!

There is another scene from a different earlier episode where Joey tries to coach Ross on talking dirty, but that doesn't involve caressing (rather Chandler eavesdropping in the background and Joey saying "Tell me you want to caress my butt!").

Its definitely NOT thisone. I distinctly remember it was Joey and Ross and Joey caressed Ross's face and Ross was very much into it :D

I would have probably made this a comment but unfortunately I don't have enough rep for it. Are you thinking about the one where they both sleep together? (non-metaphorically)
http://friends.wikia.com/wiki/The_One_With_The_Nap_Partners
